# how can I create a computed fields that is depending on another model

Tags: odoo, odoo-15

**I have two models reservation(inherit from sale.order) and places . I want to make a one2many field in the places model so when a reservation(sale.order) is confirmed, the new customer who reserved the place is added to this field**
**here is my code**

**model reservation**

```
from odoo import fields, models,api,_
from odoo.exceptions import Validation-error
class Customers2(models.Model):
    _inherit='sale.order'

client=fields.Many2one('res.partner',string='client')
secure_place=fields.Many2one(comodel_name='product.template',string='Secure place')
guests=fields.Integer(string='guests')
hotel_reser=fields.Many2one('product.template')
start_date=fields.Datetime(string='start date')
end_date=fields.Datetime(string='end date')
reserv_price=fields.Monetary(string='Price')
currency_id = fields.Many2one(comodel_name='res.currency',string='Currency')
reserv_status = fields.Selection(
    [('C', 'Confirmed'), ('D', 'Draft')],
    string='Reservation type')
```

**model places**

```
    from odoo import fields , models,api

class Place(models.Model):
    _inherit='product.template'


    hotel=fields.Selection([('H', 'Habit'),('Y','Yasmine'),('M','movenpick')],string='Hotel')
    type_of_room=fields.Selection([('S', 'spa'),('M','meeting room'),('N','Nightclub')],string='Room')
    reserv_persons=fields.One2many('sale.order','hotel_reser',string='clients reserved',compute='_compute_reservations')
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: How are `reservation` and `Places` models related?

Comment: I added the code .I would be thankful if you answer me

Comment: Did you succeed to add customers to the `reserv_persons` list?

Answer (score 0):

To add the new customer who reserved the place in the `reserv_persons` field, the related model should be `res.partner` and its type `many2many`.

You want to use a computed field (the value is computed when needed), so you can search for sale orders in the `sale` state to show all customers who reserved the `place`

***Example:***

```
from odoo import api, fields, models, _, Command


class Place(models.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.template'

    reserv_persons = fields.Many2many('res.partner', string='clients reserved', compute='_compute_reservations')

    def _compute_reservations(self):
        sale_order = self.env['sale.order']
        for tmpl in self:
            tmpl.reserv_persons = [Command.link(so.client.id) for so in sale_order.search(
                [('secure_place', '=', tmpl.id), ('state', '=', 'sale')])]
```

The [Command](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Command) used above is a special command to manipulate the relation of [One2many](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.One2many) and [Many2many](https://www.odoo.com/documentation/15.0/developer/reference/backend/orm.html#odoo.fields.Many2many)